# MYSQL statement to quickly select group from n:n table

Tags: mysql

I have an n:n set of data (for example, 'programmers' and 'languages'.  Programmers write code in many languages, and a language can be used by many programmers).  This data is in a table programmers_languages

How do I quickly select programmers who code in all of a set of languages?

More information if this is confusing:

Jon codes in C++, Pascal, and Ruby.  Joe codes in C++ and Ruby.  Moe codes in Ruby and Pascal.  Steve Codes in C++ and Pascal.

If the set of languages in question is C++ and Pascal, I would want Jon and Steve from this list.

Note the size of this set can get pretty large, so I don't want to join the table to itself n times.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm happy or sad that this question, which is in the family of `column = "foo" AND column = "bar"` catches so many wrong answers.

Comment: Is there only the one table, or are there more tables in this scenario?  And is it only ever two languages, or is it a variable number of languages that you could be filtering on?

Comment: One table, and variable number of languages.  But It would be acceptable if it handled only 4 or less languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Note the size of this set can get pretty large, so I don't want to join the table to itself n times.

Any way you shake it, there's going to be a join for each language.  You're looking for a value (programmer) for which there exists at least one row for each of another value (language).  That means that you need to think about N different perspectives of the same table.

In most cases, it's probably most efficient for you to just do the joins.  If the result set is sufficiently dense (really, most programmers speak python and c++), you could resort to some cleverness.  First query the disjunction, but uniquely, then group the resulting relation by programmer and filter out the ones that speak too few languages...

```
SELECT programmer
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT programmer, language
       FROM speaks_table
       WHERE language in ('C++', 'python') ) AS disjunction
GROUP BY disjunction.programmer
HAVING count(disjunction.language) = 2
```

But wether this outperforms a regular ol' multiway join is going to depend on the exact data in question.  This at least has the advantage of not requiring generative queries depending on the number of languages in question.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the joins are probably more efficient most of the time.  It'd be interesting to hear how big the set of data really is, though.

Comment: The data is roughly 550,000 rows, where there are ~6000 "programmers" and ~1800 "languages".  Performance is an issue, as there will be 50ish people hitting this db at once (this query is used sparingly, but I can't have it locking up the database for 20 seconds).

Comment: This is a good answer... Just depressing.  I'm surprised there isn't some efficient way to group data by programmer, and then look at each programmer in turn to check for a set of n languages.  With the size of the data, a 4x self-join would be insane.

Comment: Rereading your answer, it seems my last comment is asking for what this answer provides!  I'll test it out or speed... Thanks!

Comment: a 4x join is not neccesarily a 4 way cross product, 4 way table scan.  In fact, it's probably a single table scan, with 3 key lookups, which is really not bad at all.

Comment: To clarify.  if you need to do 4 joins, just do 4 joins.  Think about the style of my answer when you otherwise would need to do 4000 joins.

Comment: Thanks so much, a 4x join is far faster than I thought it would be.  Very usable for my use case.

Answer (score -1):

**edit**: this was my first answer and doesn't work for the question.

Assuming the table `Programmers_Languages` has two `VARCHAR` columns, one called `Programmer` and the other called `Languages`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Programmer
FROM Programmers_Languages
WHERE Language IN ('C++', 'Pascal')
ORDER BY Programmer
```

`DISTINCT` so that you only get each result once.  `ORDER BY` if you want it sorted alphabetically.

---

**edit**: different query, this works.

```
SELECT Programmers
FROM Programmers_Languages
WHERE Languages IN ('C++', 'Pascal')
GROUP BY Programmers
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
ORDER BY Programmers
```

Looks like TokenMacGuy came up with something very similar.  I'm assuming that the list of languages and the count of languages will be inserted in this query by some other code.  If you're building the query dynamically, the following would be even quicker, of course:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Programmers
FROM Programmers_Languages
WHERE Languages = 'C++'
AND   Languages = 'Pascal'
AND   <...>
ORDER BY Programmers
```

Comment: Nope.  This selects the programmers that speak at least one of those languages, but corykendall asked for a query that produces only the programmers that speak all of them.

Comment: That does not work - he needs a list of people that match ALL of the items, not just 1.

Comment: Excellent point, guys, my tired eyes misread the "and" as an "or".  Also, @corykendall, excellent question!